# Define Backbone model for content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: json, backbone.js, content-type, dataformat

I am having some issues in assigning the data to the model.
Data is coming is in the foll format.

```
"Address" : [{
   "id" : "1"
   "name" : "abc"
   "phone" : "9876543210",
   "email" : "abc@example.com"
},{
   "id" : "2"
   "name" : "XYZ"
   "phone" : "9872543210",
   "email" : "XYZ@example.com"
}]
```

But the model i have created for above looks like the foll :

```
 var AddressBookModel= Backbone.Model.extend({       
        defaults: {
            name: "",
            phone: "",
            email: ""
        },
        idAttribute: "id"
    });
```

I Know this is not the correct model created for the data.
What is the correct way to define the model for above format?

Comment: You probably want a collection to go along with your models, which can then parse the array of objects into a collection of models.

Comment: @micahbf have created foll collection - Backbone.Collection.extend({ url: 'Tasks/Task', model: addressBook.model});.But how to parse it .

Comment: If you can remove the "Address" from the json while sending data from server, I think you can get the collection in the right format and can hold by the backbone collection created.

Comment: @Sovan Yes u are correct but as we are using a third party api which send data in the given above format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are looking to "parse away" the Address object and return an array in your collection try this parse method:

```
var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function(data){
    return data.Address;
  }
});
```